# How to save output of Python API call to file

Tags: python, api, save, output

new to coding so apologies for the basic q.

I am working with an API for a cyber security tool - Virus Total. I am trying to write a program that will call the API to get the report of the IP address, and then save that report to a file. I would like each API call to be saved in a separate file with a different name (with the format 'report[number of report]-[DDMMYYYY].txt'

I have tried to accomplish this with the open and write commands, but I am getting error: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

I have successfully got the API response but I do not know how to save it to a file with an automatically changing filename.

Any ideas?

I will post my code below (with my API key redacted).

Thanks

```
url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/192.169.69.25"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "x-apikey": "REDACTED"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

with open("testoutput1.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, so you likely already have this solved, but for future searches, you likely want to save the json response (`f.write(response.json())`) or raw text (`f.write(response.text)`) rather than the `response` directly, which is what the `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` is indicating.

Here is an example with minor changes to use `pathlib` and format the filename based on your request:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

import requests

url = "https://catfact.ninja/fact"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

# # As a tip, breakpoint can be very helpful when debugging. Try:
# breakpoint()

idx = 1  # Hypothetical index from a for-loop
date = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y")
Path(f"report{idx}-{date}.json").write_text(json.dumps(response.json()))
```

As a side-note, with Python 3.10, you can now get a much more helpful error message: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Response`